# System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, error-handling

I want to display some columns from the database in textboxes. When I run the code, there is an error on `@ApplicantUsername`

> IndexOutOfRangeException

Here is my code:

```
        cs.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ApplicantUsername, Branch, DescriptionOfHouse, DescritpionOfHouseType, LivingCondition, MembersOfHousehold, RealProperty, PersonalProperty, Collaterals, PurposeOfLoan, LoanDesired, MaxLoanVal, PromisoryNoteVal, MonthlyInstallment1, Terms, TotalMonthlyIncome, TotalMonthlyExpenses, Class, NarrativeReport FROM CustomerCreditReport WHERE ApplicantUsername = '" + uname + "'", cs);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txtUsername.Text = reader["@ApplicantUsername"].ToString();
            txtBranch.Text = reader["@Branch"].ToString();
            txtDesc.Text = reader["@DescriptionOfHouse"].ToString();
            txtOAR.Text = reader["@DescritpionOfHouseType"].ToString();
            txtCond.Text = reader["@LivingCondition"].ToString();
            txtMem.Text = reader["@MembersOfHousehold"].ToString();
            txtReal.Text = reader["@RealProperty"].ToString();
            txtPersonal.Text = reader["@PersonalProperty"].ToString();
            txtCollateral.Text = reader["@Collaterals"].ToString();
            txtPurpose.Text = reader["@PurposeOfLoan"].ToString();
            txtDesired.Text = reader["@LoanDesired"].ToString();
            txtMLV.Text = reader["@MaxLoanVal"].ToString();
            txtPNV.Text = reader["@PromisoryNoteVal"].ToString();
            txtMI.Text = reader["@MonthlyInstallment1"].ToString();
            txtTerms.Text = reader["@Terms"].ToString();
            txtTotIncome.Text = reader["@TotalMonthlyIncome"].ToString();
            txtTotExpenses.Text = reader["@TotalMonthlyExpenses"].ToString();
            txtClass.Text = reader["@Class"].ToString();
            txtNarrative.Text = reader["@NarrativeReport"].ToString();
        }
        cs.Close();
```

Can you please help my find a way to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: try reader.HasRows() in the while condition

Comment: Here is my table schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `@` from all those field-names.

You use the `@` for parameters that you add to your parameterized query (you have no parameters in your example). To retrieve the values from the columns like you're doing, you should not use `@`, just the plain names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the correct code below. You should not use @ while reading the data from datareader.

```
    cs.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ApplicantUsername, Branch, DescriptionOfHouse, DescritpionOfHouseType, LivingCondition, MembersOfHousehold, RealProperty, PersonalProperty, Collaterals, PurposeOfLoan, LoanDesired, MaxLoanVal, PromisoryNoteVal, MonthlyInstallment1, Terms, TotalMonthlyIncome, TotalMonthlyExpenses, Class, NarrativeReport FROM CustomerCreditReport WHERE ApplicantUsername = '" + uname + "'", cs);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        txtUsername.Text = reader["ApplicantUsername"].ToString();
        txtBranch.Text = reader["Branch"].ToString();
        txtDesc.Text = reader["DescriptionOfHouse"].ToString();
        txtOAR.Text = reader["DescritpionOfHouseType"].ToString();
        txtCond.Text = reader["LivingCondition"].ToString();
        txtMem.Text = reader["MembersOfHousehold"].ToString();
        txtReal.Text = reader["RealProperty"].ToString();
        txtPersonal.Text = reader["PersonalProperty"].ToString();
        txtCollateral.Text = reader["Collaterals"].ToString();
        txtPurpose.Text = reader["PurposeOfLoan"].ToString();
        txtDesired.Text = reader["LoanDesired"].ToString();
        txtMLV.Text = reader["MaxLoanVal"].ToString();
        txtPNV.Text = reader["PromisoryNoteVal"].ToString();
        txtMI.Text = reader["MonthlyInstallment1"].ToString();
        txtTerms.Text = reader["Terms"].ToString();
        txtTotIncome.Text = reader["TotalMonthlyIncome"].ToString();
        txtTotExpenses.Text = reader["TotalMonthlyExpenses"].ToString();
        txtClass.Text = reader["Class"].ToString();
        txtNarrative.Text = reader["NarrativeReport"].ToString();
    }
    cs.Close();
```